# How can I force the "select" to return to "Choose..." after submit form in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, react-bootstrap

How can I force the "select" to return to "Choose..." after submit form?

```
<select name="activated" className="form-control" as="select" onChange={handleInputChange}>  
         <option value={values.activated} selected>Choose...</option>           
         <option value="Activated">Activated</option>
         <option value="Deactivated">Deactivated</option>     
</select>
```

I think I have to use the blur or focus method.  Some idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import Select from 'react-select';

export class Test extends Component {
  this.setState = {
    selection: 0,
   };

  onSelectChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ selection: e.value });
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { selection } = this.state;
    // Post request logic comes here
    // Reset Select component to original default state
    this.setState({selection: 0});
  }

  render() {

    const options = [
      { label: 'Choose something', value: 0 },
      { label: 'Item 1', value: 1 },
      { label: 'Item 2', value: 2 },
    ];

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <Select
          options={options}
          value={this.state.selection}
          onChange={this.onSelectChange}
        />
       //submit button here          
      </form>
    );
```

Use value prop instead of defaultValue and manage it through state.On Submit, reset that state to initial value i.e 0.

Answer (score 1):

I found a simpler solution than Tayyab's answer:

Adding this code to my handleSubmit function:

```
document.getElementById("myId").selectedIndex = 0
```

Comment: You should accept this answer if it's the one you went with; you can still vote Tayyab's answer up if you found it useful/helpful.